# disable auto update of datasets parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Every time i pick a value from one of the parameters combos - the datasets that connected by filltering to the chosen dataset are automatic update by sending queries to the SQL DB .

The avaiable values lists that contains the datasets are not change.

I need that each query will be exceute only when the report is inital and not every time I change value of parameter.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are each getting their `Default Values` from a dataset. If you look in the dataset properties and then Parameters, you'll find that the first parameter is being passed into the datasets of the successive parameters. These parameters are being used as filters to limit the options.

What you need to do is remove the parameter references from these datasets. You will find that the parameters are in the queries, so you'll have to update the query to not use those filters and remove them from the Parameters tab.

Once you've done that, each dataset will run once and not change as you select parameter values.